# How to start the x-axis ticks at 1 (instead of 0) when plotting a Numpy array using Seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's assume the following array of length 15:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0.17, 0.15, 0.13, 0.12, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02])
arr

array([0.17, 0.15, 0.13, 0.12, 0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03,
       0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02])
```

I take the cumulative sum of this array and assign it to `cum_arr`:

```
cum_arr = np.cumsum(arr)
cum_arr

array([0.17, 0.32, 0.45, 0.57, 0.64, 0.7 , 0.75, 0.8 , 0.83, 0.86, 0.89,
       0.92, 0.95, 0.98, 1.  ])
```

Now, I'd like to simply plot this array using a Seaborn's `lineplot`.

My attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x_range = [x for x in range(1, len(cum_arr) +1)]

ax = sns.lineplot(data=cum_arr)
ax.set_xlim(1, 15)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_xticks(x_range)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Notice how the y coordinate associated with 1 on the x-axis is 0.32, which corresponds to the ***second*** element in `cum_arr`.

The desired plot would look something like this:

[image]

How would I start plotting at the first element in `cum_arr`? (or alternatively adjust the xticks to take this into account)

Thanks!

Comment: You never used `x_range` in your call to `lineplot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only pass a 1-D data series to the plotting function then all it can do is plot the data against the index (0,1,2...) which is what is happening. So the problem is that you are not defining the values that `cum_arr` are to be plotted against.  Just defining `x_range` as you have done has no effect if it is not passed to the plotting function. To specify the x and y you should use:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(y= cum_arr, x= x_range)
```

and you will get the expected plot.

Answer (score 0):

Start the range at 0 instead of 1 when populating x_range

`x_range = [x for x in range(0, len(cum_arr) + 1)]`

Did this solve your problem?